# Bootstrap badge style did not change with the parent style change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the html panel div with badge like something below:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">Title<span class="badge pull-right">#1</span></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I change the panel style from "**panel-info**" to something else in jquery, the behaviour of badge in the panel head did not changed automatically as expected.

So, is there any way to let the badge style follow the change of the parent style?

Thanks.

Comment: The badge style should update automatically. Check your javascript and make sure it is doing what is intended. Here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ewbphmo0/) that toggles the panel-info class and the badge style changes automatically

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by upgrading my bootstrap from v3.0 to the newest version 3.3.5

Lisoft